# While I am communicating with the bitcoin average server it says 403 status code error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
request(" https://apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/all?crypto=BTC&fiat=USD,EUR", function(error, response, body){
console.log(response.statusCode);
});

});

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log("server is running in port 3000");
});
```

While I am communicating with the bitcoin average server it says 403 status code error.

Answer (score 1):

if you see the body of response `console.log(response.body);` see this error and

> Unauthenticated requests can't access endpoint
>   apiv2.bitcoinaverage.com/indices/global/ticker/all?crypto=BTC&fiat=USD,EUR

403 is for [unauthorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) ("refuses to authorize"); i.e. 'I know who you are, but you don't have permission to access this resource.'

> 403 Forbidden
>
> The 403 (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
>   the request but refuses to authorize it. A server that wishes to make
>   public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in
>   the response payload (if any).
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server
>   considers them insufficient to grant access. The client SHOULD NOT
>   automatically repeat the request with the same credentials. The client
>   MAY repeat the request with new or different credentials. However, a
>   request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.
>
> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a
>   forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of
>   404 (Not Found).

you should [Making Authenticated Requests](https://portal.liferay.dev/docs/7-1/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/t/making-authenticated-requests)

Comment: thank you so much sir work perfectly i copied the wrong link